# Azure Application Insights for Android

Tags: android, azure-application-insights

Im trying to implemenet app insights in my android app
I have tried using this in y Application class

```
AppCenter.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
        AppCenter.start((Application) getApplicationContext(), "{df2331b5-fcc9-4c3a-9971-2f4aabad120b}", Analytics.class, Crashes.class);
```

The response Im getting is

```
AppCenter: HTTP response status=401 payload={"status":"AppSecretDenied","validDiagnosticsIds":[],"throttledDiagnosticsIds":[],"correlationId":"971eea9b-bce9-40cb-abc0-ee5030a0984f"}
```

In my Activity im using

```
 Analytics.trackEvent("Dashboard");
```

Comment: Are you still using App Center with your Android app?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in my main activity:

```
//APP_CENTER_SECRET
Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity.onCreate: starting AppCenter...");
AppCenter.start(getApplication(), BuildConfig.APP_CENTER_SECRET,
                Analytics.class, Crashes.class);
```